# "Provide with" or simply "Provide"

Tags: grammaticality

Is it grammatically correct " Which is correct sentence: "Please provide me with the following documents" or "Please provide me the following documents"

Comment: The **provide** + IO + DO ditransitive construction is, I'd say, marginally available ('... will also provide you the way of escape' appears in the Bible (ICor 10:13) in at least one version). But I'd normally avoid it.

Answer (score 6):

Subject at all times to anything @John Lawler may say, I think it is because the verb "provide" is ditransitive.

*Please provide the documents*, and *Please provide me with the documents* are both correct. (But *Please provide me the documents* is NOT correct).

In the first instance the direct object is "the documents", but in the second, where "me" becomes the direct object then "documents" is indirect and hence requires a preposition -"with".